# Override properties and system properties in spring xml

Tags: java, spring

in my Spring configuration I have the following line:

```
<context:property-placeholder
   location="/META-INF/spring/global.properties,#{systemProperties['external.propertyFile'] ?: ''}, /WEB-INF/local.properties"
   ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

My intention is to have some defaults shipped in `global.properties`and these should be overridable by another external file passed in through `external.propertyFile` and some properties are kept local by the application itself in `local.properties`

From what I see in the logs - `global.properties`and `local.properties` are processed right but the substitution with `#{systemProperties ... }` doesn't seem to work here.

Any hint's how to fix that or work around it?

Here's the related log from my app (shortened a bit):

```
Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/META-/spring/counter.properties]
Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/#{systemProperties['external.propertyFile'] ?: ''}]
   WARN support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer: Could not load properties from ServletContext resource [/#{systemProperties['external.propertyFile'] ?: ''}]: Could not open ServletContext resource [/#{systemProperties['external.propertyFile'] ?: ''}]
Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/local.properties]
```

---

Just a remark:

In other places of the same XML configuration the substitution works fine - eg. with:

```
<util:properties
   id="myProp"
   location="#{systemProperties['my.propertyFile'] ?: '/META-INF/spring/my.properties'}"/>
```

But this time I need a more complex way to handle/merge the actual property values :(

Comment: If you use Maven, take a look at [Maven Resource Filtering](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_filter_resource_files) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked OK for me

```
<context:property-placeholder
   location="/META-INF/spring/global.properties,${external.propertyFile},/WEB-INF/local.properties"
   ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks - seems that I was blind :(